# Parameters of a Weka Classifier

Tags: java, eclipse, weka, classification

I use Weka. I would like to access the parameters (the weights) of a classifier. 
What I want to do is to access the values of the parameters to determine how they have an influence on the attributes.

So, my questions are :

- How to access to the parameters of a Classifier ? (with Eclipse)
- How to determine the related attributes of a parameter ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a related question about weights in WEKA: [How to use weights in Weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801228/how-to-use-weights-in-weka)

And here is an example of java code: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Add+weights+to+dataset

To find out about the relationship between attributes you can use `Ranker` as a searcher and `PrincipalComponents` as a evaluator in `Selecte attributes` tab. And you will get a correlation matrix like this one:

```
Correlation matrix
  1     -0.11   0.87   0.82 
 -0.11   1     -0.42  -0.36 
  0.87  -0.42   1      0.96 
  0.82  -0.36   0.96   1
```

Comment: In Weka Explorer, we can access to the relevant attributes; but we don't have an numerical information; do you know if it's possible to have more information about how it's calculated ?

Comment: In explorer, just go to `Select attributes`, then select an evaluator and a searcher and you will get numerical results. Every algorithm in WEKA is documented and it has references to its paper that has a full explanation about the algorithm.

Comment: What I obtain is only that : 

Selected attributes: 21,39,46,55,63,134,... : 50
                      adore
                      album
                      americain
                     ...
But I would like to have "weight" for each word.

Comment: Ok; I think it's good thank you. With InfoGainAttributeEval and Ranker, I have values. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Weka Documentation](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code#Classification-Building%20a%20Classifier) there is a section on building a classifier. I am not 100% what parameters you are wanting to set but I believe reading through this should help. I was not able to quickly find the list of Options available, but that would be a good place to look too as I recall some of the options being very useful when I was using Weka a few years back.

**EDIT:** I believe what you want then are 'attribute weights'. I don't have much experience with them, though I recall seeing these being applied by accompanying [XRFF files](http://weka.wikispaces.com/XRFF#Additional%20features) to alter the data set prior to classification. To find the XRFF attribute weight page I came across [this post](https://list.scms.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2009-August/045043.html) which may prove useful.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've already seen the documentation but I didn't find an answer for my question. I want a numerical value for each attribute that refects how it influence the result.

Comment: I don't know if it's really what I want; is it really related with a specific classifier ?